# Why is User.Invoke("SetPassword") using my computer's current credentials and how I can I specify them instead?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am able to create new users in a remote ActiveDirectory server, which I am doing using an admin account on that server. This is how I do that:

```
String connection = "LDAP://serveraddress/OU=NewUsers,OU=People,DC=mydomain,DC=local";
usersDirectoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(connection, "adminUserName","adminPass");
DirectoryEntry newUser = usersDirectoryEntry.Children.Add(userString, "user");
newUser.CommitChanges();
```

However, immediately after I am trying to set the password using:

```
UpdatePassword(newUser, "userPasswordMeetsRequirements");
```

where

```
private static void UpdatePassword(DirectoryEntry User, String password)
{
    User.Properties["pwdLastSet"].Value = -1;
    User.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { password.Trim() });
    User.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = 0x0200 | 0x10000;
    User.CommitChanges();
}
```

Where User is of type DirectoryEntry (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry(v=vs.110).aspx)

And on the User.Invoke line I get a System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException --> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied.

That admin user should indeed have set password permissions. After looking in the AD logs I found that at the User.Invoke line my program was trying to connect to the AD server using my current credentials on my computer (which is on a different domain).

Why is this happening, and how can I force it to just use the admin account that it used for user creation?

Comment: What class is User an instance of, and how do you instantiate it? A little more code please.

Comment: @FrankHagenson DirectoryEntry, very commonly used when working with ActiveDirectory. Please see my edit.

Comment: Out of curiosity what is the value of `newUser.Username` and what is the value of `User.Username`? Are they both returning "*adminUserName*"?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain no, neither equals adminUserName. adminUserName is the username of the admin account on the AD server, whereas the User object is for the user that we are creating, and that username is set in the code, but not equal to the admin username.

Comment: @user145400 Then there's your problem, if you read [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.username(v=vs.110).aspx) for `Username` it says "*Gets or sets the user name to use when authenticating the client.*", it needs to be the admin username, not the user you are creating. If that property is not being inherited to the new object created in your `Children.Add` call you need to manually set it. You will likely need to set `DirectoryEntry.Password` to "*adminPass*" too.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Nope. Notice how there are 2 DirectoryEntry objects: usersDirectoryEntry and newUser. The one used to authenticate (usersDirectoryEntry) does indeed use the admin credentials. The user is indeed created successfully. There is nothing wrong with that part.

Comment: I am assuming you did `UpdatePassword(newUser, "newPassword")` (you don't show what is between your two code examples), if you want `User.CommitChanges();` to work inside `UpdatePassword` then the `DirectoryEntry` you passed in (`newUser`) needs to have the administrative credentials set in `User.Username` and `User.Password`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain yes, I do that. There is nothing really between the two code examples, I edited again to show that. I verified inside my UpdatePassword() method that the admin user and pass are present in the User object.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an answer to this yet is there?

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing that newUser object to UpdatePassword? I would assume it's using the same credentials.

But if not, you can create a new object like this:

```
var user = new DirectoryEntry(newUser.Path, "adminUserName","adminPass");
UpdatePassword(user, somepassword);
```

Comment: Yes I am passing it in. Which is why I was surprised when I was told that the AD logs show my username and domain (which is different) when the program was at the User.Invoke line. The authentication attempt for user creation did use the specified credentials correctly.

Comment: Yeah, that's strange. Does it work if you create a new object like in my code example? I'm automating account creations for my work, but I run the service under the privileged credentials, so I don't need to pass them in my code.

Comment: Your code seems to be setting the admin user's password, whereas I want to authenticate using the admin user but change a different (specified at runtime) user's password.

Comment: The first line creates a new DirectoryEntry pointing to the new account. It pulls the Path from the newUser object, which will be in "LDAP://..." format and authenticates with your admin username and password. The second line passes that new DirectoryEntry object to your UpdatePassword method with the password to set. That will set the password on the new account.

Comment: Yes, my previous comment was wrong. But I confirmed that I am already doing what you wrote. In my UpdatePassword method, the DirectoryEntry object has its username and password attributes set to the admin user and password.

Comment: Are you sure that admin account has the right permissions? Try opening AD Users and Computers with that admin account and reset the password of the new account.

Answer (score 0):

Begining on .NET 3.5 and newer, you can use the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`

You can find information about it in [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement(v=vs.110).aspx).

Why don't you try the following  :

```
PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext( ContextType.Domain, null, adAdminLogin, adAdminPassword );
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity( context, adUserLogin );
user.SetPassword( adUserNewPassword );
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is one of the first things I had tried, only to find that internally it does use User.Invoke() itself and gave me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able swicth to 3 diff domain using this (just changing domain LDAP path)
i don't see why you couldn't.

```
Domain = "LDAP://domain2.com";
ADUSER = MySuperAdmin;
ADpassword = "123";                 
DirectoryEntry Entry = new DirectoryEntry(Domain, ADUSER, ADpassword);
 DirectoryEntry Entry = new DirectoryEntry(Domain, ADUSER, ADpassword);

                DirectorySearcher Search = new DirectorySearcher(Entry);
                Search.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectCategory=computer)(cn={0}))", HostName);

                    SearchResult Result = Search.FindOne();
```

now check if your are able find a device on your targeted  domain 
if it work try change the password if you not able it have nothing to do with the C# code but more with "MySuperAdmin" rigth on the domain2 .try direct in mmc you should pop the same error than in your application.

maybee a checkbox  "User cannot change password" may cause the fail too